# Join in spark dataframe (scala) based on not null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Suppose I've two dataframes like following :

First -

```
A    | B    | C    | D
1a   | 1b   | 1c   | 1d
2a   | null | 2c   | 2d
3a   | null | null | 3d
4a   | 4b   | null | null
5a   | null | null | null
6a   | 6b   | 6c   | null
```

Second -

```
P    | B    | C    | D
1p   | 1b   | 1c   | 1d
2p   | 2b   | 2c   | 2d
3p   | 3b   | 3c   | 3d
4p   | 4b   | 4c   | 4d 
5p   | 5b   | 5c   | 5d
6p   | 6b   | 6c   | 6d
```

The join operation is performed based on {"B", "C", "D"}. In case of null occurring in any of these columns, it should check for not null values occurring in remaining columns.

So, the result should be like -

```
P    | B    | C    | D    | A
1p   | 1b   | 1c   | 1d   | 1a
2p   | null | 2c   | 2d   | 2a
3p   | null | null | 3d   | 3a
4p   | 4b   | null | null | 4a // First(C) & First(D) was null so we take only B
6p   | 6b   | 6c   | null | 6a
```

Can anyone suggest any solution for this query ? 
Currently I am trying to filter values having null values in single column, two columns, three columns. Then joining them with Second without taking that column. For eg - 
I first filtered out values having only B as null from First. Then joining it with Second based on "C" and "D".
In this way, I will get many dataframes and I will finally union them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df1.join(broadcast(df2), df1("B") === df2("B") || df1("C") === df2("C") || df1("D") === df2("D"))
  .drop(df2("B"))
  .drop(df2("C"))
  .drop(df2("D"))
  .show(false)
```

to be more safe you can `broadcast` the `dataframe` which is smaller in size.

Comment: Your solution is correct to some extent. So, I extended your solution to this - '"df1.join(broadcast(df2),  (((df2("B")===null) || (df1("B") === df2("B"))) && ((df2("C")===null) || (df1("C") === df2("C"))) && ((df2("D")===null) || (df1("D") === df2("D")))))
  .drop(df2("B"))
  .drop(df2("C"))
  .drop(df2("D"))
  .show(false)"
It means that it should df1(Col) should either be null or equal to df2(Col)
But still I am getting only single row - 1a |1p |1b |1c |1d 
But not others. Any idea why ?

Comment: isn't it the solution for your question ? :) hehehe. Thats because you are using &&. And why are you using `df2("B")===null)`? null values are in df1, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but you should try `    df1.join(broadcast(df2), (
      ((df2("B")==="null") || (df1("B") === df2("B"))) &&
      ((df2("C")==="null") || (df1("C") === df2("C"))) &&
      ((df2("D")==="null") || (df1("D") === df2("D")))))
      .drop(df2("B")) .drop(df2("C")) .drop(df2("D")) .show(false)`. But you should be aware which dataframe has the null values. According to your question df1 has null values not df2

Answer (score 0):

I think left join should do the work, try the following code :

```
val group = udf((p1: String, p2: String, p3: String) => if (p1 != null) p1 else if (p2 != null) p2 else if (p3 != null) p3 else null)
val joined = first.join(second.select("B", "P"), Seq("B"), "left")
                  .withColumnRenamed("P", "P1")
                  .join(second.select("C", "P"), Seq("C"), "left")
                  .withColumnRenamed("P", "P2")
                  .join(second.select("D", "P"), Seq("D"), "left")
                  .withColumnRenamed("P", "P3")
                  .select($"A", $"B", $"C", $"D", group($"P1", $"P2", $"P3") as "P")
                  .where($"P".isNotNull)
```

Hope this helps you, otherwise comment your problems

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've edited my question. There was some mistake. And I've tried using your solution. But I am getting "null" value instead of "4a" (see in the commented line)

Comment: what if you try to join just on `B` @Ishan ?

Comment: I've to first join based on B, C and D.. if any one column is having null then I'll have to join based on another two. Similarly, if two columns having null values at the same time then I'll join based on 3rd one.

Comment: @Ishan I've edited the answer try it and give the results

Comment: I've displayed the result I'm getting from your solution. See the updated question.

Comment: @Ishan I've edited the answer, I've tested the code and it worked for me. If It worked with you please up-vote and make my answer as the recommended one