# Spark Dataframes join with 2 columns using or operator

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Dataframe 1:

```
+---------+---------+
|login_Id1|login_Id2|
+---------+---------+
|  1234567|  1234568|
|  1234567|     null|
|     null|  1234568|
|  1234567|  1000000|
|  1000000|  1234568|
|  1000000|  1000000|
+---------+---------+
```

DataFrame 2:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
|login_Id|user_name| user_Email|
+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
| 1234569|TestUser3|user3_Email|
| 1234570|TestUser4|user4_Email|
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Expected Output

```
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|login_Id1|login_Id2|login_Id|user_name| user_Email|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1234567|  1234568| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|  1234567|     null| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|     null|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
|  1234567|  1000000| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|  1000000|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
|  1000000|  1000000|    null|     null|       null|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

My requirement is I have to join both the dataframes so as to get the additional information for each login Id from DataFrame 2.Either login_Id1 or login_Id2 will have data(in most of the cases).At times both the columns may also have data.In that case I want to use login_Id1 to perform join.When both of the columns doesn't match I want null as result

I followed this link

[Join in spark dataframe (scala) based on not null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815703/join-in-spark-dataframe-scala-based-on-not-null-values)

I tried with

```
DataFrame1.join(broadcast(DataFrame2), DataFrame1("login_Id1") === DataFrame2("login_Id") || DataFrame1("login_Id2") === DataFrame2("login_Id") )
```

The output that I get is

```
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|login_Id1|login_Id2|login_Id|user_name| user_Email|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1234567|  1234568| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|  1234567|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
|  1234567|     null| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|     null|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
|  1234567|  1000000| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|  1000000|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
|  1000000|  1000000|    null|     null|       null|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

I get the expected behavior when either of the columns have value.When both of them have values,a join is performed with both the columns(Row1,Row3).In this case || doesn't short circuit?

Is there a way I can get the Expected dataframe?

As of now,I have a udf function that checks if login_Id1 has value(returns login_Id1) or login_Id2 has value(returns login_Id2), if both of them have values I am returning loginId1,and add the result of the udf function as another column(Filtered_Login_id) to the DataFrame1.

Dataframe1 after adding FilteredId column with udf

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
|loginId1|loginId2 | FilteredId|
+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1234567|1234568  |1234567    |
| 1234567|null     |1234567    |
| null   |1234568  |1234568    |
| 1234567|1000000  |1234567    |
| 1000000|1234568  |1000000    |
| 1000000|1000000  |1000000    |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Then I perform join based on FilteredId ===loginId and get the result

```
DataFrame1.join(broadcast(DataFrame2), DataFrame1("FilteredId") === DataFrame2("login_Id"),"left_outer" )
```

Is there a better way to achieve this result without udf?just with join(which behaves like short circuit or operator)?

Included the use case pointed out by Leo.My udf approach misses out the use case pointed out by Leo.My exact requirement is if any of the 2 input column values(login_Id1,login_Id2) match with the login_Id of Dataframe2,that loginId data should be fetched.If either of the columns doesn't match it should add null(something like left outer join)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me whether your sample data already covers all scenarios of the `login_Id`-pairs.  If it does, a solution focusing on `null` checking will suffice; otherwise it would require something slightly more complex (such as your using of `UDF`).

One approach without relying on `UDF` is to apply `left_outer` join on `df1` and `left_semi` join on `df2` each with an additional `flag` column for preference ordering, combine them via `union`, join `df2` for including the non-key columns, and finally eliminate duplicated rows based on `flag`.

Here's sample code with slightly more generalized sample data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = Seq(
  ("1234567", "1234568"),
  ("1234567", null),
  (null, "1234568"),
  ("1234569", "1000000"),
  ("1000000", "1234570"),
  ("1000000", "1000000")
).toDF("login_Id1", "login_Id2")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("1234567", "TestUser1", "user1_Email"),
  ("1234568", "TestUser2", "user2_Email"),
  ("1234569", "TestUser3", "user3_Email"),
  ("1234570", "TestUser4", "user4_Email")
).toDF("login_Id", "user_name", "user_Email")

val dfOuter = df1.join(df2, $"login_Id1" === df2("login_Id"), "left_outer").
  withColumn("flag", when($"login_Id".isNull, lit(9)).otherwise(lit(1))).
  select("login_Id1", "login_Id2", "flag")
// +---------+---------+----+
// |login_Id1|login_Id2|flag|
// +---------+---------+----+
// |  1234567|  1234568|   1|
// |  1234567|     null|   1|
// |     null|  1234568|   9|
// |  1234569|  1000000|   1|
// |  1000000|  1234570|   9|
// |  1000000|  1000000|   9|
// +---------+---------+----+

val dfSemi = df1.join(df2, $"login_Id2" === df2("login_Id"), "left_semi").
  withColumn("flag", lit(2))
// +---------+---------+----+
// |login_Id1|login_Id2|flag|
// +---------+---------+----+
// |  1234567|  1234568|   2|
// |     null|  1234568|   2|
// |  1000000|  1234570|   2|
// +---------+---------+----+

val window = Window.partitionBy("login_Id1", "login_Id2").orderBy("flag")

(dfOuter union dfSemi).
  withColumn("row_num", row_number.over(window)).
  where($"row_num" === 1).
  withColumn("login_Id", when($"flag" === 1, $"login_Id1").
    otherwise(when($"flag" === 2, $"login_Id2"))
  ).
  join(df2, Seq("login_Id"), "left_outer").
  select("login_Id1", "login_Id2", "login_Id", "user_name", "user_Email")
// +---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
// |login_Id1|login_Id2|login_Id|user_name| user_Email|
// +---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
// |  1000000|  1000000|    null|     null|       null|
// |  1000000|  1234570| 1234570|TestUser4|user4_Email|
// |  1234567|  1234568| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
// |  1234569|  1000000| 1234569|TestUser3|user3_Email|
// |  1234567|     null| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
// |     null|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
// +---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Note that you can apply `broadcast` to `df2` like in your existing sample code if it's significantly smaller compared with `df1`.  In case `df2` is small enough to be `collect`-ed, it can be much simplified to something as follows:

```
val loginIdList = df2.collect.map(r => r.getAs[String](0))

val df1Unmatched = df1.where(
  !$"login_Id1".isin(loginIdList: _*) && !$"login_Id2".isin(loginIdList: _*)
)

(df1 except df1Unmatched).
  join( broadcast(df2), $"login_Id1" === $"login_Id" ||
    ($"login_Id2" === $"login_Id" &&
      ($"login_Id1".isNull || !$"login_Id1".isin(loginIdList: _*))
    )
  ).
  union(
    df1Unmatched.join(df2, $"login_Id2" === $"login_Id", "left_outer")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Leo for catching this use case where either of the columns have values that is not present in Dataframe2.That is also part of the requirement.Missed out on that.Will update my question to include this case.I will try out your solution and will let you know if it works for me

Comment: Both the solutions works, just wanted to know how small should the dataframe2 to be for using collect?dataframe2 in my case has 25000k records..

Comment: It largely depends on the hardware configurations (in particular, memory).  I normally wouldn't apply `collect` to any RDD/DataFrame with over a couple millions of rows.

Comment: ohk thanks,how do I convert your approach for left outer join?I tried but couldn't modify it.I have edited my question accordingly.Appreciate your help

Comment: @Aradhana, the requirement of including `login_Id`-pair (with neither `id` in `df2`) makes things a little more complex.  Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only want the second column if the first is null, add that condition to your join clause:

```
@ df1.join(df2, df1("login_Id1") <=> df2("login_Id") || (df1("login_Id1").isNull && df1("login_Id2") <=> df2("login_Id"))).show()
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|login_Id1|login_Id2|login_Id|user_name| user_Email|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1234567|  1234568| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|  1234567|     null| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|     null|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Note: the right hand side finds this row only:

```
@ df1.join(df2, df1("login_Id1").isNull && df1("login_Id2") <=> df2("login_Id")).show()
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|login_Id1|login_Id2|login_Id|user_name| user_Email|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|     null|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, solves the null case, as per my initial question, my bad missed to include the use case mentioned by Leo :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `coalesce` function to create a new value that's either `login_Id1` (if it's not null) or `login_Id2` (if 1 was null) - and compare that result to `login_Id`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val res = DataFrame1.join(DataFrame2, coalesce($"login_Id1", $"login_Id2") === $"login_Id")

res.show()
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|login_Id1|login_Id2|login_Id|user_name| user_Email|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1234567|     null| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|  1234567|  1234568| 1234567|TestUser1|user1_Email|
|     null|  1234568| 1234568|TestUser2|user2_Email|
+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, solves the null case, as per my initial question, my bad missed to include the use case mentioned by Leo :)