# How can I make a unique match with join with two spark dataframes and different columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes spark(scala):

First:

```
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
|id                 |zone              |zone_father      |father_id |country          |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
|2                  |1                 |123              |1         |0                |
|2                  |2                 |123              |1         |0                |
|3                  |3                 |1                |2         |0                |
|2                  |4                 |123              |1         |0                |
|3                  |5                 |2                |2         |0                |
|3                  |6                 |4                |2         |0                |
|3                  |7                 |19               |2         |0                |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
```

Second:

```
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|country            |id                |zone             |zone_value       |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|0                  |2                 |1                |7                |
|0                  |2                 |2                |7                |
|0                  |2                 |4                |8                |
|0                  |0                 |0                |2                |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Then I need following logic:

1 -> If => first.id = second.id && first.zone = second.zone

2 -> Else if => first.father_id = second.id && first.zone_father = second.zone

3 -> If neither the first nor the second is true, follow the latter => first.country = second.zone

And the expected result would be:

```
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|id                 |zone              |zone_father      |father_id |country          |zone_value       |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|2                  |1                 |123              |1         |0                |7                |
|2                  |2                 |123              |1         |0                |7                |
|3                  |3                 |1                |2         |0                |7                |
|2                  |4                 |123              |1         |0                |8                |
|3                  |5                 |2                |2         |0                |7                |
|3                  |6                 |4                |2         |0                |8                |
|3                  |7                 |19               |2         |0                |2                |
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I tried to join both dataframes, but due "or" operation, two results for each row is returned, because the last premise returns true regardless of the result of the other two.

Comment: Can you share any code you currently have? This would allow for suggested changes/adjustments.

Comment: Have you take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800174/how-to-join-two-dataframes-in-scala-and-apache-spark ?
This post details joining with an OR condition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905407/spark-dataframes-join-with-2-columns-using-or-operator